# Eventhough I didn't use static I get below warning

Tags: android, android-studio

I get "non-static variable *variable* cannot be referenced from a static context" warning eventhough I didn't use **static** expression at Android Studio. I don't understand why. Could you please help?

I've tried to share code but because it's too long I couldn't.

Problem starts after onClick method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    // gameStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    newRoundButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newRound);
    hitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hit);
    newGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newGame);
    passButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pass);

    playerC1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playerC1);


    newRoundButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    hitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    newGameButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    passButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    //hitButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    //newGameButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    // passButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    dealer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dealer);
    player = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player);
    playerTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerTotal);
    dealerDeckTable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dealerDeckTable);
    playerDeckTable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerDeckTable);
    skor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    gameMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameMessage);
    dealerTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dealerTotal);
    playerSkor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerSkor);
    dealerSkor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dealerSkor);
    kontrol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kontrol);
    playerDeckTable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerDeckTable);
    dealerDeckTable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dealerDeckTable);

    playerC1.setImageDrawable((ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.nocard)));

}
 public void onClick(View v) {
   if (v.getId() == newGameButton.getId()) {
        gameMessage.setText(Cards.firstStart());
        playerSkor.setText(Cards.pskorS);
        dealerSkor.setText(Cards.dskorS);
        playerTotal.setText(Cards.pValS);
        dealerTotal.setText("N/A");
        playerDeckTable.setText(Cards.pHand);
        dealerDeckTable.setText(Cards.dHand2);
        newGameButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        kontrol.setText(Cards.kontrolS);
```

*code continues...*

**Cards** class does not contain any static variable and I get that warning lines getting information from **Cards** class.

I hope details are enough to explain the problem..

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: Please add the logcat and some code

Comment: I shared. I hope its enough...

Comment: You are probably attempting to reference a local variable inside an anonymous class or a lambda

Comment: you say there is no static variable in the `Cards` class then how can you access variable like they were static. Like here `Cards.pskorS`. This should be something like `new Cards().pskorS`.

Comment: well I get the "non-static variable variable cannot be referenced from a static context" warnings at those class and that's my problem...

Comment: Of course, you would because you are trying to access them like they were static. See my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Prolem is, that u call Cards.firstStart() like a static method. You should initialize your Cardobject with `Cards cards = new Cards()`